# ListBox items change after doing scroll in Firemonkey

Tags: android, scroll, listbox, firemonkey, listboxitems

I am developing a Multi-Device Application in Firemonkey where Main class has a ListBox component with some items. Each of these items has the same custom style.

My problem is when I have so many items in the ListBox and I have to do scroll vertical to see the rest of items. In this case, the ListBox has a strange behaviour and when I do scroll up after doing scroll down the item's components (a button for example) have changed his background colour and the items have changed his order inside ListBox.

For example, if I had:

1. Item 1
2. Item 2
3. Item 3

after I do scroll I have:

1. Item 2
2. Item 3
3. Item 1

This change is random. Each time is different.

Real example (process steps):

1. Load the Main class where is ListBox.

[image]

2. Do vertical scrolling down to see the rest of items.
3. Do vertical scrolling upward to return to the top of the list.

[image]

4. The items have changed position in the ListBox and the button (component of each item) changes its background color.

Why I have this behaviour in the ListBox?? How I can solve it and the ListBox do not change items order neither background colour of his components?

I do not know if there is any property to block items inside ListBox or similar ...

**EDIT**

This is the code to create and initialize the ListBox items:

```
procedure TRooms_Form.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  ...
begin
    i := 0;
    while i < numItems do begin
      //Create ListBox item
       item := TListBoxItem.Create(nil);
       item.Parent := myListBox;
       item.StyleLookup := 'styleLBox';
      //Number
       itemNumber := item.FindStyleResource('btt_number') as TButton;
       if Assigned(itemNumber) then begin
           itemNumber.Text := jsonNumber;
           case jsonColor of
             0 : itemNumber.TintObject.TintColor := TAlphaColors.Chocolate; 
             1 : itemNumber.TintObject.TintColor := TAlphaColors.Gold;      
             2 : itemNumber.TintObject.TintColor := TAlphaColors.Darkgreen; 
             3 : itemNumber.TintObject.TintColor := TAlphaColors.Deeppink;  
           end;
         end;
      //Title
       itemTitle := item.FindStyleResource('txtstyle_title') as TText;
       if Assigned(itemTitle) then begin
         itemTitle.Text := jsonTitle;
       end;
      //Occupation
       itemOccup := item.FindStyleResource('txt_occupation') as TText;
       if Assigned(itemOccup) then begin
         itemOccup.Text := jsonOccup;
       end;
      //Dates
       itemDay := item.FindStyleResource('txt_day') as TText;
       if Assigned(itemDay) then itemDay.Text := displayDay;
       itemDateStart := item.FindStyleResource('txt_start') as TText;
       if Assigned(itemDateStart) then itemDateStart.Text := jsonTimeStart;
       itemDateEnd := item.FindStyleResource('txt_end') as TText;
       if Assigned(itemDateEnd) then itemDateEnd.Text := jsonTimeEnd;
      //Item background
       itemBackgr := item.FindStyleResource('background_item') as TRectangle;
       if Assigned(itemBackgr) then begin
         itemBackgr.Fill.Kind := TBrushKind.Solid;
         case jsonStatus of
           0 : itemBackgr.Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.White;         
           1 : itemBackgr.Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.Lightgreen;    
           2 : itemBackgr.Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.Palegoldenrod; 
           3 : itemBackgr.Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.Lightcoral;    
           4 : itemBackgr.Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.Lightseagreen; 
           5 : itemBackgr.Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.Lightblue;     
           6 : itemBackgr.Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.Lightgrey;     
         end;
       end;
      //Empty item
       if (StrToInt(jsonEmpty) = 1) or (StrToInt(jsonNull) = 1) then begin
         startDetail[i] := False;
         if Assigned(itemNumber) then itemNumber.Visible := False;
         if Assigned(itemOccup) then itemOccup.Visible := False;
       end
       else begin
         startDetail[i] := True;
       end;

       Inc(i);
    end;
```

Thanks so much for your attention.

Comment: Can you please explain the steps to reproduce as easy as possible. Can you reproduce this on both platforms Android and Win?

Comment: @Kerem D I have edited my post. XD

Comment: There are still not enough informations. I asked on which platforms you have this behaviour. Can you reproduce it with the predefined 'ItemStyle's.  Can you reproduce it with a more simple custom style?

Comment: I am having this behaviour in Android (my App does not work in Windows and I not yet tried it on iPhone). Reproduce it with another style is a little complex, I have to do changes in my code.

Comment: It's not possible for me to rebuild your example. You have to provide an easier one, so that I could reproduce your problem.

Comment: Do you not know why it happen in my ListBox? It is something strange ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some days and some tests, I have already found a solution to my problem.

I do not understand well why but there was some code lines that they were interfering with my custom style.

For example, when I put:

```
//Item background
   itemBackgr := item.FindStyleResource('background_item') as TRectangle;
   if Assigned(itemBackgr) then begin
     **itemBackgr.Fill.Kind := TBrushKind.Solid;**
     ...
```

After scroll, items changed order position and their color background. I have applied this property directly in the 'TRectangle' component in the custom style.

Moreover, I changed the allocation of all elements to this way:

-Before I had:

```
   itemTitle := item.FindStyleResource('txtstyle_title') as TText;
   if Assigned(itemTitle) then begin
     itemTitle.Text := jsonTitle;
   end;
```

-Now, I have:

```
   item.StylesData['txtstyle_title'] := jsonTitle;
```

With these changes I get items do not change their position in ListBox neither background color after scroll.

I had a problem yet, buttons do not show their background color and it was due to these lines:

```
//Empty item
   if (StrToInt(jsonEmpty) = 1) or (StrToInt(jsonNull) = 1) then begin
     startDetail[i] := False;
     **if Assigned(itemNumber) then itemNumber.Visible := False;**
     **if Assigned(itemOccup) then itemOccup.Visible := False;**
   end
   else begin
     startDetail[i] := True;
   end;
```

Apparently, you cannot change visible property from item in 'FormCreate' method because when you do scroll some items elements change their property without control. Therefore, I have done some modifications in my code instead of putting to false the visibility:

```
    if (StrToInt(jsonEmpty) = 1) or (StrToInt(jsonNull) = 1) then begin
      startDetail[i] := False;
      item.StylesData['btt_number.Text'] := '';
      item.StylesData['txt_occupation'] := '';
      if (StrToInt(jsonEmpty) = 1) then item.StylesData['btt_number.TintObject.TintColor'] := TAlphaColors.White;
      if (StrToInt(jsonNull) = 1) then item.StylesData['btt_number.TintObject.TintColor'] := TAlphaColors.Lightblue;
    end
    else begin
      startDetail[i] := True;
      item.StylesData['btt_number.Text'] := jsonNumber;
      item.StylesData['txt_occupation'] := jsonOccup;
    end;
```

At this form, I put the text ' ' (empty) and the background color at the same color that his item (TRectangle) in the elements who should to have the visible property to false.

After all these changes I get the result that I wanted, that is to say, my items ListBox do not change when I scroll. XD

Answer (score 0):

Changing the StyleBook on the form to Resourse1 helped me.