# Why Listbox items change order position and colour background after do scrolling in Firemonkey?

Tags: android, scroll, listbox, firemonkey

I am developing a Multi-Device Application in Firemonkey where Main class has a ListBox component with some items. Each of these items has the same custom style.

My problem is when I have so many items in the ListBox and I have to do scroll vertical to see the rest of items. In this case, the ListBox has a strange behaviour and when I do scroll up after doing scroll down the item's components (a button for example) have changed his background colour and the items have changed his order inside ListBox.

For example, if I had:

*Item 1*

*Item 2*

*Item 3*

after I do scroll I have:

*Item 2*

*Item 3*

*Item 1*

This change is random. Each time is different.

Real example (process steps):

1. Load the Main class where is ListBox.

[image]

2. Do vertical scrolling down to see the rest of items.
3. Do vertical scrolling upward to return to the top of the list.

[image]

4. The items have changed position in the ListBox and the button (component of each item) changes its background color.

Why I have this behaviour in the ListBox??

How I can solve it and the ListBox do not change items order neither background colour of his components?

I do not know if there is any property to block items inside ListBox or similar ...

**EDIT**

This is the code to create and initialize the ListBox items:

```
procedure TRooms_Form.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  ...
begin
    i := 0;
    while i < numItems do begin
      //Create ListBox item
       item := TListBoxItem.Create(nil);
       item.Parent := myListBox;
       item.StyleLookup := 'styleLBox';
      //Number
       itemNumber := item.FindStyleResource('btt_number') as TButton;
       if Assigned(itemNumber) then begin
           itemNumber.Text := jsonNumber;
           case jsonColor of
             0 : itemNumber.TintObject.TintColor := TAlphaColors.Chocolate; 
             1 : itemNumber.TintObject.TintColor := TAlphaColors.Gold;      
             2 : itemNumber.TintObject.TintColor := TAlphaColors.Darkgreen; 
             3 : itemNumber.TintObject.TintColor := TAlphaColors.Deeppink;  
           end;
         end;
      //Type
       itemType := item.FindStyleResource('txtstyle_type') as TText;
       if Assigned(itemType) then begin
         itemType.Text := jsonTypeName;
       end;
      //Occupation
       itemOccup := item.FindStyleResource('txt_occupation') as TText;
       if Assigned(itemOccup) then begin
         itemOccup.Text := jsonOccup;
       end;
      //Dates
       itemDay := item.FindStyleResource('txt_day') as TText;
       if Assigned(itemDay) then itemDay.Text := displayDay;
       itemDateStart := item.FindStyleResource('txt_start') as TText;
       if Assigned(itemDateStart) then itemDateStart.Text := jsonTimeStart;
       itemDateEnd := item.FindStyleResource('txt_end') as TText;
       if Assigned(itemDateEnd) then itemDateEnd.Text := jsonTimeEnd;
      //Item background
       itemBackgr := item.FindStyleResource('background_item') as TRectangle;
       if Assigned(itemBackgr) then begin
         itemBackgr.Fill.Kind := TBrushKind.Solid;
         case jsonStatus of
           0 : itemBackgr.Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.White;         
           1 : itemBackgr.Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.Lightgreen;    
           2 : itemBackgr.Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.Palegoldenrod; 
           3 : itemBackgr.Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.Lightcoral;    
           4 : itemBackgr.Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.Lightseagreen; 
           5 : itemBackgr.Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.Lightblue;     
           6 : itemBackgr.Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.Lightgrey;     
         end;
       end;

       Inc(i);
    end;
```

Thanks so much for your attention.

**EDIT 2. SOLUTION**

[ListBox items change after doing scroll in Firemonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38219295/listbox-items-change-after-doing-scroll-in-firemonkey/38498936#38498936)

Comment: This is normal behaviour if you dont take precautions reusing list items that get recycled.

Comment: How should I be careful and do so that items do not change their position?

Comment: In getView() normally. But did you Google already for recycling listview items?

Comment: But, I create Listbox items in the 'FormCreate' method in Delphi ... is this method in Delphi or only in Java? Moreover, is a Listbox, not a Listview.

Comment: Hmmm... Maybe the listbox is implemented with a listview? I dont know... Why dont you show some code? How is it possible that a listbox item can display several strings... like a listview? The VCL listbox can only display one string. You work with an adapter?

Comment: Do you speak about Java or Delphi?? In Firemonkey you can define some style for your ListBox items or another elements, then a Listbox item can display all strings that you want ... I do not use Adapter, is not necessary in Firemonkey, that is in Java ...

Comment: In your code i ment.

Comment: How? Can you explain me please? Do you say that I could put my code?

Comment: I do not know Firemonkey so how could i deliver code for it? It is you that should show how he build up that listbox and handles it.

Comment: I have edited my post with the code to create ListBox items

Comment: You must have some kind of layout definition as where 'btt_number' comes from? And others.

Comment: Why isnt itemNumber locally defined for that while loop. And others.

Comment: All elements in my class are created in the 'Structure' section (like a layout in Java) and they are defined in the 'var' section of the method where I have put '...'

Comment: You better google for this recycle problem. What did you find? Or ask in the Embarcadero forum. Or that of the new owner. More people will have encountered this problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38219295. You have asked this before and @Kerem D was willing to try it out. Why didnt you supply full code and layout?

Comment: You could try to use a TLlistView instead of a TListBox.

Comment: Use a ListView is to change so many things in my code, I could try it but it will be my last option. I thought that someone could have this problem or similar ...

Comment: First start a new project with a TListView to investigate the behaviour. You should also start a new project with a simple TListBox that shows the recycling problem. Then you can post the whole project in case someone wants to try it out. The site effect of all this could be that you discover what you did wrong. Well in case its not a bug in fire monkey.

Comment: Yes, if anyone answer my question I will try to do new project with a ListView or an easier ListBox. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ListBox items change after doing scroll in Firemonkey](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38219295/listbox-items-change-after-doing-scroll-in-firemonkey)

Comment: I have already found a solution to my problem!! You can click in the link who appears in the post to see it. XD